# comparing PDF report to Database

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pdf, nlp

I have  one  use-case .Lets say there is pdf report which has data from testing of some manufacturing components
and this PDF report is loaded in DB using some internally developed software.
We need to develop some reconciliation program wherein the data needs to be compared from PDF report to Database. We can assume pdf file has a  fixed template.

If there are many tables and some raw text data in pdf then how mysql save this pdf data..in One table or in many tables .

Please suggest some approach(preferably in python) for comparing data

Answer (score 0):

[Finding and extracting specific text from URL PDF files, without downloading or writing (solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68676118/finding-and-extracting-specific-text-from-url-pdf-files-without-downloading-or) have a look at this example and see if it will help. I found it worked efficiently for me, this is if the pdf is URL based, but you could simply change the input source to be your DB. In your case you can remove the two `if` statements under the `if isinstance(obj, pdfminer.layout.LTTextBoxHorizontal):` line. You mention having PDFs with the same template, if you are looking to extract text from one specific area of the template, use the print statement that has been commented out to find coordinates of desired data. Then as is done in the example, use those coordinates in `if` statements.